# Beamer slides jump from using `\only`

Tags: beamer

I was trying to use `\only` to dynamically show the some bullets. The problem is that the slides, "First and second" in the following example, will "jump" when I turn to the next page. How can I avoid it? I know if I change `\only` to `\onslide`, the slide will not jump. But unlike `\only`, `\onslide` has to reserve the space first.

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\begin{document}
\begin{frame}[plain]
    First and second.\\ % This line will jump while turning page.
    \only<1>{
        \begin{itemize}
            \item 1.a
            \item 1.b
        \end{itemize}
    }
    \only<2>{
        \begin{itemize}
            \item 2.a
            \item 2.b
            \item 2.c
        \end{itemize}
    }

\end{frame}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Beamer keeping line position constant on itemize](http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/123268/beamer-keeping-line-position-constant-on-itemize)

Comment: The answers at https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/148/34551 are detailed and offer more variation, even if Gonzalo Medina's answer is quite good and probably enough for most cases.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Use an `overlayarea` environment, designed specially to prevent those "jumps":

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\begin{document}
\begin{frame}[plain]

\begin{overlayarea}{\textwidth}{4cm}
    First and second.
    \only<1>{
        \begin{itemize}
            \item 1.a
            \item 1.b
        \end{itemize}
    }
    \only<2>{
        \begin{itemize}
            \item 2.a
            \item 2.b
            \item 2.c
        \end{itemize}
    }
\end{overlayarea}
\end{frame}

\end{document}
```

The result:

[image]

Comment: Alternatively, use `\begin{overprint} ... \end{overprint}`, it doesn't need height or width specification. See [Beamer user guide](https://mirrors.ctan.org/macros/latex/contrib/beamer/doc/beameruserguide.pdf) for more information.